# Little JQuery interaction

Tags: jquery, function, this

This is one of the 10

```
<li class="application">
    <img class="iconapp" ..../>
    <p>
        <span class="spancat">....</span>
        <span class="prix>....</span>
        <span class="description">....</span>

        <span class="panier">
            <img .../>
        </span>
    </p>
</li>
```

So i'm trying that when I click on the ".panier", it puts the the value of the alt attribute of the ".iconapp" in a new div. I'm having a hard time as I have 10 < li> like the one above, and when I click on any ".panier" of any < li>, I always get the att of the .icon that is in the first < li> (in the alert).

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(function ()    {
    $(".panier").click(function ()
    {
        var nom = $(".iconeapp").attr("alt");
        alert(nom);
        $("#divcat").append("<div id='appspanier'>HOLLA</div>");
    })
})
```

Hopefully you will be able to help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$(".iconapp")` it selects all elements with that class, and then the `.attr()` method grabs an attribute from the first one (as you've seen). To relate the clicked item to the `.iconapp` within the same `li` first start from `this` (the clicked item) and navigate up through the DOM to the [`.closest("li")`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then within that li [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) its `.iconapp`:

```
$(function ()    {
    $(".panier").click(function ()
    {
        var nom = $(this).closest("li").find(".iconapp").attr("alt");
        alert(nom);
        $("#divcat").append("<div id='appspanier'>HOLLA</div>");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! Can you explain with detail this line:
var nom = $(this).closest("li").find(".iconeapp").attr("alt");

Comment: You're welcome. There are other jQuery DOM navigation methods like `.parent()`, `.next()` (sibling), `.prev()` (sibling) and so forth, but generally `.closest().find()` is more robust because it doesn't rely on quite so specific an html structure.